# as.data.frame() no column names (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following list:

```
result
[[1]]
 [1]  NA 104  67  NA 107  71  94  NA  NA  64

[[2]]
 [1]  NA 381  NA  NA 412  NA 287  NA  NA  NA

[[3]]
 [1] NA 38 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

With `dput()`:

```
list(c(NA, 104, 67, NA, 107, 71, 94, NA, NA, 64), c(NA, 381, 
NA, NA, 412, NA, 287, NA, NA, NA), c(NA, 38, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

---

Now I'd like to convert this list to a `dataframe`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, result), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                    col.names = c('speed', 'distance', 'degrees'))
```

Unfortunately, this does not include the colum names in the output (why?):

```
df
    V1  V2 V3
1   NA  NA NA
2  104 381 38
3   67  NA NA
4   NA  NA NA
5  107 412 NA
6   71  NA NA
7   94 287 NA
8   NA  NA NA
9   NA  NA NA
10  64  NA NA
```

Comment: From `as.data.frame` help, it seems that it does not use the `col.names` parameter when working with matrix class. If you use `result`(a list) instead of `do.call(cbind, result)`, you get the column names.

Comment: Try `setNames(as.data.frame(result,stringsAsFactors=FALSE),c('speed', 'distance', 'degrees'))`. Or just `as.data.frame(result,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,col.names=c('speed', 'distance', 'degrees'))`.

Comment: @nicola: Thanks. I know how to set the names (`colnames()` etc.) but the question remains why the parameter is not recognized?

Comment: Done. Why it behaves this way, I don't really know.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This post is about "list to data.frame", the target post is about "matrix to data.frame".

Comment: @zx8754: Honestly, it is. You can check with `a <- do.call(cbind, result); class(a);` which outputs "matrix" - thus it is.

Comment: Up to you, but you are creating unnecessary step by making a matrix out of a list, then trying to convert to a data.frame. Also, in case you didn't know, *data.frame* **is** a list and *data.frame* function just adds dims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `as.data.frame` help, it seems that the function does not use the `col.names` parameter when applied on a matrix. If you use `result` (the original list) instead of `do.call(cbind, result)`, you get the column names.

Answer (score 5):

The *result* list doesn't have names, give it names then convert, no need for *cbind*:

```
result <- list(c(NA, 104, 67, NA, 107, 71, 94, NA, NA, 64),
               c(NA, 381, NA, NA, 412, NA, 287, NA, NA, NA),
               c(NA, 38, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

df1 <- data.frame(setNames(result, c("speed", "distance", "degrees")))

head(df1)
#   speed distance degrees
# 1    NA       NA      NA
# 2   104      381      38
# 3    67       NA      NA
# 4    NA       NA      NA
# 5   107      412      NA
# 6    71       NA      NA
```